# How can I implement a simple virtual keyboard for a website using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

How can I implement a simple virtual keyboard for a website? The only thing I need is a number pad (0-9).

I hope there is a way to implement it as simple as possible using the JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement a simple virtual keyboard for a website... only required number pad(0-9)...

Please find the following code :

```
<HTML><HEAD><SCRIPT type="text/javascript">function VNumpad(container_id, callback_ref, font_name, font_size,
                 font_color, bg_color, key_color, border_color,
                 show_click, click_font_color, click_bg_color,
                 click_border_color, do_embed, do_gap)  {
return this._construct(container_id, callback_ref, font_name, font_size,
                       font_color, bg_color, key_color, border_color,
                       show_click, click_font_color, click_bg_color,
                       click_border_color, do_embed, do_gap);  }  VNumpad.kbArray = [];  VNumpad.prototype = {

_setup_event: function(elem, eventType, handler)
{
  return (elem.attachEvent ? elem.attachEvent("on" + eventType, handler) : ((elem.addEventListener) ? elem.addEventListener(eventType, handler, false) : null));
},

_start_flash: function(in_el)
{
  function getColor(str, posOne, posTwo)
  {
    if(/rgb\((\d+),\s(\d+),\s(\d+)\)/.exec(str)) // try to detect Mozilla-style rgb value.
    {
      switch(posOne)
      {
        case 1: return parseInt(RegExp.$1, 10);
        case 2: return parseInt(RegExp.$2, 10);
        case 3: return parseInt(RegExp.$3, 10);
        default: return 0;
      }
    }
    else // standard (#xxxxxx or #xxx) way
      return str.length == 4 ? parseInt(str.substr(posOne, 1) + str.substr(posOne, 1), 16) : parseInt(str.substr(posTwo, 2), 16);
  }

  function getR(color_string)
  { return getColor(color_string, 1, 1); }

  function getG(color_string)
  { return getColor(color_string, 2, 3); }

  function getB(color_string)
  { return getColor(color_string, 3, 5); }

  var el = in_el.time ? in_el : (in_el.company && in_el.company.time ? in_el.company : null);
  if(el)
  {
    el.time = 0;
    clearInterval(el.timer);
  }

  var vkb = this;
  var ftc = vkb.fontcolor, bgc = vkb.keycolor, brc = vkb.bordercolor;

  // Special fixes for simple/dead/modifier keys:

  if(in_el.dead)
    ftc = vkb.deadcolor;

  if(((in_el.innerHTML == "Shift") && vkb.Shift) || ((in_el.innerHTML == "Caps") && vkb.Caps) || ((in_el.innerHTML == "AltGr") && vkb.AltGr))
    bgc = vkb.lic;

  // Extract base color values:
  var fr = getR(ftc), fg = getG(ftc), fb = getB(ftc);
  var kr = getR(bgc), kg = getG(bgc), kb = getB(bgc);
  var br = getR(brc), bg = getG(brc), bb = getB(brc);

  // Extract flash color values:
  var f_r = getR(vkb.cfc), f_g = getG(vkb.cfc), f_b = getB(vkb.cfc);
  var k_r = getR(vkb.cbg), k_g = getG(vkb.cbg), k_b = getB(vkb.cbg);
  var b_r = getR(vkb.cbr), b_g = getG(vkb.cbr), b_b = getB(vkb.cbr);

  var _shift_colors = function()
  {
    function dec2hex(dec)
    {
      var hexChars = "0123456789ABCDEF";
      var a = dec % 16;
      var b = (dec - a) / 16;

      return hexChars.charAt(b) + hexChars.charAt(a) + "";
    }

    in_el.time = !in_el.time ? 10 : (in_el.time - 1);

    function calc_color(start, end)
    { return (end - (in_el.time / 10) * (end - start)); }

    var t_f_r = calc_color(f_r, fr), t_f_g = calc_color(f_g, fg), t_f_b = calc_color(f_b, fb);
    var t_k_r = calc_color(k_r, kr), t_k_g = calc_color(k_g, kg), t_k_b = calc_color(k_b, kb);
    var t_b_r = calc_color(b_r, br), t_b_g = calc_color(b_g, bg), t_b_b = calc_color(b_b, bb);

    in_el.style.color = "#" + dec2hex(t_f_r) + dec2hex(t_f_g) + dec2hex(t_f_b);
    in_el.style.borderColor = "#" + dec2hex(t_b_r) + dec2hex(t_b_g) + dec2hex(t_b_b);
    in_el.style.backgroundColor = "#" + dec2hex(t_k_r) + dec2hex(t_k_g) + dec2hex(t_k_b);

    if(!in_el.time)
    {
      clearInterval(in_el.timer);
      return;
    }
  };

  _shift_colors();

  in_el.timer = window.setInterval(_shift_colors, 50);
},

_setup_style: function(obj, top, left, width, height, position, border_color, bg_color, text_align, line_height, font_size, font_weight, padding_left, padding_right)
{
  var os = obj.style;

  if(top)    os.top = top;
  if(left)   os.left = left;
  if(width)  os.width = width;
  if(height) os.height = height;

  if(position) os.position = position;

  if(border_color) os.border = "1px solid " + border_color;
  if(bg_color) os.backgroundColor = bg_color;

  if(text_align)  os.textAlign  = text_align;
  if(line_height) os.lineHeight = line_height;
  if(font_size)   os.fontSize   = font_size;

  os.fontWeight = font_weight || "bold";

  if(padding_left)  os.paddingLeft  = padding_left;
  if(padding_right) os.paddingRight = padding_right;
},

_setup_key: function(parent, id, top, left, width, height, border_color, bg_color, text_align, line_height, font_size, font_weight, padding_left, padding_right)
{
  var _id = this.Cntr.id + id;
  var exists = document.getElementById(_id);

  var key = exists ? exists.parentNode : document.createElement("DIV");
  this._setup_style(key, top, left, width, height, "absolute");

  var key_sub = exists || document.createElement("DIV");
  key.appendChild(key_sub); parent.appendChild(key);

  this._setup_style(key_sub, "", "", "", line_height, "relative", border_color, bg_color, text_align, line_height, font_size, font_weight, padding_left, padding_right);
  key_sub.id = _id;

  if(!exists) this._setup_event(key_sub, 'mouseup', this._generic_callback_proc);

  return key_sub;
},

_findX: function(obj)
{ return (obj && obj.parentNode) ? parseFloat(obj.parentNode.offsetLeft) : 0; },

_findY: function(obj)
{ return (obj && obj.parentNode) ? parseFloat(obj.parentNode.offsetTop) : 0; },

_findW: function(obj)
{ return (obj && obj.parentNode) ? parseFloat(obj.parentNode.offsetWidth) : 0; },

_findH: function(obj)
{ return (obj && obj.parentNode) ? parseFloat(obj.parentNode.offsetHeight) : 0; },

_construct: function(container_id, callback_ref, font_name, font_size, font_color, bg_color, key_color, border_color,
                     show_click, click_font_color, click_bg_color, click_border_color, do_embed, do_gap)
{
  var exists  = (this.Cntr != undefined), ct = exists ? this.Cntr : document.getElementById(container_id);
  var changed = (font_size && (font_size != this.fontsize));

  this._Callback = ((typeof(callback_ref) == "function") && ((callback_ref.length == 1) || (callback_ref.length == 2))) ? callback_ref : (this._Callback || null);

  var ff = font_name || this.fontname || "";
  var fs = font_size || this.fontsize || "14px";

  var fc = font_color   || this.fontcolor   || "#000";
  var bg = bg_color     || this.bgcolor     || "#FFF";
  var kc = key_color    || this.keycolor    || "#FFF";
  var bc = border_color || this.bordercolor || "#777";

  this.cfc = click_font_color   || this.cfc || "#CC3300";
  this.cbg = click_bg_color     || this.cbg || "#FF9966";
  this.cbr = click_border_color || this.cbr || "#CC3300";

  this.sc = (show_click == undefined) ? ((this.sc == undefined) ? false : this.sc) : show_click;
  this.gap = (do_gap != undefined) ? (do_gap ? 1 : -1) : (this.gap || 1);

  this.fontname = ff, this.fontsize = fs, this.fontcolor = fc;
  this.bgcolor = bg,  this.keycolor = kc, this.bordercolor = bc;

  if(!exists)
  {
    this.Cntr = ct, this.LastKey = null;

    VNumpad.kbArray[container_id] = this;
  }

  var kb = exists ? ct.childNodes[0] : document.createElement("DIV");

  if(!exists)
  {
    ct.appendChild(kb);
    ct.style.display = "block";
    ct.style.zIndex  = 999;

    if(do_embed)
      ct.style.position = "relative";
    else
    {
      ct.style.position = "absolute";

      var initX = 0, initY = 0, ct_ = ct;
      if(ct_.offsetParent)
      {
        while (ct_.offsetParent)
        {
          initX += ct_.offsetLeft;
          initY += ct_.offsetTop;

          ct_ = ct_.offsetParent;
        }
      }
      else if (ct_.x)
      {
        initX += ct_.x;
        initY += ct_.y;
      }

      ct.style.top = initY + "px", ct.style.left = initX +"px";
    }

    kb.style.position = "relative";
    kb.style.top      = "0px", kb.style.left = "0px";
  }

  kb.style.border = "1px solid " + bc;

  var kb_main = exists ? kb.childNodes[0] : document.createElement("DIV"), ks = kb_main.style;
  if(!exists)
  {
    kb.appendChild(kb_main);

    ks.position = "relative";
    ks.width    = "1px";
    ks.cursor   = "default";
  }

  // Disable content selection:
  this._setup_event(kb_main, "selectstart", function(event) { return false; });
  this._setup_event(kb_main, "mousedown",   function(event) { if(event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault(); return false; });

  ks.fontFamily = ff, ks.backgroundColor = bg;

  if(!exists || changed)
  {
    ks.width  = this._create_numpad(container_id, kb_main);
    ks.height = (this._findY(this.LastKey) + this._findH(this.LastKey) + this.gap) + "px";
  }

  return this;
},

_create_numpad: function(container_id, parent)
{
  var c = "center", n = "normal", l = "left", gap = this.gap;
  var fs = this.fontsize, kc = this.keycolor, bc = this.bordercolor;

  var mag = parseFloat(fs) / 14.0, cell = Math.floor(25.0 * mag);
  var dcell = 2 * cell, dp = (dcell + 1) + "px", dp2 = (dcell - 1 - ((gap < 0) ? 2 : 0)) + "px";
  var cp = String(cell) + "px", lh = String(Math.floor(cell - 2.0)) + "px";

  var edge = gap + "px";

  var kb_pad_eur = this._setup_key(parent, "___pad_eur", gap + "px", edge, cp, cp, bc, kc, c, lh, fs);
  kb_pad_eur.innerHTML = "&#x20AC;";

  var edge_1 = (this._findX(kb_pad_eur) + this._findW(kb_pad_eur) + gap) + "px";

  var kb_pad_slash = this._setup_key(parent, "___pad_slash", gap + "px", edge_1, cp, cp, bc, kc, c, lh, fs);
  kb_pad_slash.innerHTML = "/";

  var edge_2 = (this._findX(kb_pad_slash) + this._findW(kb_pad_slash) + gap) + "px";

  var kb_pad_star = this._setup_key(parent, "___pad_star", gap + "px", edge_2, cp, cp, bc, kc, c, lh, fs);
  kb_pad_star.innerHTML = "*";

  var edge_3 = (this._findX(kb_pad_star) + this._findW(kb_pad_star) + gap) + "px";

  var kb_pad_minus = this._setup_key(parent, "___pad_minus", gap + "px", edge_3, cp, cp, bc, kc, c, lh, fs);
  kb_pad_minus.innerHTML = "-";

  this.kbpM = this._findX(kb_pad_minus) + this._findW(kb_pad_minus) + gap;

  var prevH = this._findH(kb_pad_eur), edge_Y = (this._findY(kb_pad_eur) + prevH + gap) + "px";

  var kb_pad_7 = this._setup_key(parent, "___pad_7", edge_Y, edge, cp, cp, bc, kc, c, lh, fs);
  kb_pad_7.innerHTML = "7";

  var kb_pad_8 = this._setup_key(parent, "___pad_8", edge_Y, edge_1, cp, cp, bc, kc, c, lh, fs);
  kb_pad_8.innerHTML = "8";

  var kb_pad_9 = this._setup_key(parent, "___pad_9", edge_Y, edge_2, cp, cp, bc, kc, c, lh, fs);
  kb_pad_9.innerHTML = "9";

  var kb_pad_plus = this._setup_key(parent, "___pad_plus", edge_Y, edge_3, cp, dp, bc, kc, c, dp2, fs);
  kb_pad_plus.innerHTML = "+";

  edge_Y = (this._findY(kb_pad_7) + prevH + gap) + "px";

  var kb_pad_4 = this._setup_key(parent, "___pad_4", edge_Y, edge, cp, cp, bc, kc, c, lh, fs);
  kb_pad_4.innerHTML = "4";

  var kb_pad_5 = this._setup_key(parent, "___pad_5", edge_Y, edge_1, cp, cp, bc, kc, c, lh, fs);
  kb_pad_5.innerHTML = "5";

  var kb_pad_6 = this._setup_key(parent, "___pad_6", edge_Y, edge_2, cp, cp, bc, kc, c, lh, fs);
  kb_pad_6.innerHTML = "6";

  edge_Y = (this._findY(kb_pad_4) + prevH + gap) + "px";

  var kb_pad_1 = this._setup_key(parent, "___pad_1", edge_Y, edge, cp, cp, bc, kc, c, lh, fs);
  kb_pad_1.innerHTML = "1";

  var kb_pad_2 = this._setup_key(parent, "___pad_2", edge_Y, edge_1, cp, cp, bc, kc, c, lh, fs);
  kb_pad_2.innerHTML = "2";

  var kb_pad_3 = this._setup_key(parent, "___pad_3", edge_Y, edge_2, cp, cp, bc, kc, c, lh, fs);
  kb_pad_3.innerHTML = "3";

  var kb_pad_enter = this._setup_key(parent, "___pad_enter", edge_Y, edge_3, cp, dp, bc, kc, c, dp2, parseFloat(fs) * 0.643, n);
  kb_pad_enter.innerHTML = "Enter";

  edge_Y = (this._findY(kb_pad_1) + prevH + gap) + "px";

  var kb_pad_0 = this._setup_key(parent, "___pad_0", edge_Y, edge, dp, cp, bc, kc, l, lh, fs, "", 7 * mag + "px");
  kb_pad_0.innerHTML = "0";

  var kb_pad_period = this._setup_key(parent, "___pad_period", edge_Y, edge_2, cp, cp, bc, kc, c, lh, fs);
  kb_pad_period.innerHTML = ".";

  this.LastKey = kb_pad_period;

  return String(this._findX(kb_pad_minus) + this._findW(kb_pad_minus) + gap) + "px";
},

_generic_callback_proc: function(event)
{
  var e = event || window.event;
  var in_el = e.srcElement || e.target;
  var container_id = in_el.id.substring(0, in_el.id.indexOf("___"));

  var vpad = VNumpad.kbArray[container_id];

  if(vpad.sc) vpad._start_flash(in_el);

  if(vpad._Callback) vpad._Callback(in_el.innerHTML, vpad.Cntr.id);
},

SetParameters: function()
{
  var l = arguments.length;
  if(!l || (l % 2 != 0)) return false;

  var p0, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9, p10;

  while(--l > 0)
  {
    var value = arguments[l];

    switch(arguments[l - 1])
    {
      case "callback":
        p0 = ((typeof(value) == "function") && ((value.length == 1) || (value.length == 2))) ? value : this._Callback;
        break;

      case "font-name":  p1 = value; break;
      case "font-size":  p2 = value; break;
      case "font-color": p3 = value; break;
      case "base-color": p4 = value; break;
      case "key-color":  p5 = value; break;

      case "border-color": p6 = value; break;
      case "show-click":   p7 = value; break;

      case "click-font-color":   p8  = value; break;
      case "click-key-color":    p9 = value; break;
      case "click-border-color": p10 = value; break;

      default: break;
    }

    l -= 1;
  }

  this._construct(this.Cntr.id, p0, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9, p10);

  return true;
}, Show: function(value){
  var ct = this.Cntr.style;
  ct.display = ((value == undefined) || (value == true)) ? "block" : ((value == false) ? "none" : ct.display); }}; </SCRIPT> <SCRIPT><!--

 var opened = false, vkb = null, text = null, insertionS = 0, insertionE = 0;

 var userstr = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
 var isgecko = (userstr.indexOf('gecko') != -1) && (userstr.indexOf('applewebkit') == -1);

 function numpad_change()
 {
   document.getElementById("switch").innerHTML = (opened ? "Show numpad" : "Hide numpad");
   opened = !opened;

   if(opened && !vkb)
   {
     vkb = new VNumpad("numpad",     // container's id
                       pad_callback, // reference to the callback function
                       "",           // font name ("" == system default)
                       "14px",       // font size in px
                       "#000",       // font color
                       "#FFF",       // keyboard base background color
                       "#FFF",       // keys' background color
                       "#777",       // border color
                       true,         // show key flash on click? (false by default)
                       "#CC3300",    // font color for flash event
                       "#FF9966",    // key background color for flash event
                       "#CC3300",    // key border color for flash event
                       false,        // embed VNumpad into the page?
                       true);        // use 1-pixel gap between the keys?

   }
   else
     vkb.Show(opened);

   text = document.getElementById("textfield");
   text.focus();

   if(document.attachEvent)
     text.attachEvent("onblur", backFocus);
 }

 function backFocus()
 {
   if(opened)
   {
     setRange(text, insertionS, insertionE);

     text.focus();
   }
 }

 // Advanced callback function:
 //
 function pad_callback(ch)
 {
   var val = text.value;

   switch(ch)
   {
     case "BackSpace":
       if(val.length)
       {
         var span = null;

         if(document.selection)
           span = document.selection.createRange().duplicate();

         if(span && span.text.length > 0)
         {
           span.text = "";
           getCaretPositions(text);
         }
         else
           deleteAtCaret(text);
       }

       break;

     default:
       insertAtCaret(text, (ch == "Enter" ? (window.opera ? '\r\n' : '\n') : ch));
   }
 }

 // This function retrieves the position (in chars, relative to
 // the start of the text) of the edit cursor (caret), or, if
 // text is selected in the TEXTAREA, the start and end positions
 // of the selection.
 //
 function getCaretPositions(ctrl)
 {
   var CaretPosS = -1, CaretPosE = 0;

   // Mozilla way:
   if(ctrl.selectionStart || (ctrl.selectionStart == '0'))
   {
     CaretPosS = ctrl.selectionStart;
     CaretPosE = ctrl.selectionEnd;

     insertionS = CaretPosS == -1 ? CaretPosE : CaretPosS;
     insertionE = CaretPosE;
   }
   // IE way:
   else if(document.selection && ctrl.createTextRange)
   {
     var start = end = 0;
     try
     {
       start = Math.abs(document.selection.createRange().moveStart("character", -10000000)); // start

       if (start > 0)
       {
         try
         {
           var endReal = Math.abs(ctrl.createTextRange().moveEnd("character", -10000000));

           var r = document.body.createTextRange();
           r.moveToElementText(ctrl);
           var sTest = Math.abs(r.moveStart("character", -10000000));
           var eTest = Math.abs(r.moveEnd("character", -10000000));

           if ((ctrl.tagName.toLowerCase() != 'input') && (eTest - endReal == sTest))
             start -= sTest;
         }
         catch(err) {}
       }
     }
     catch (e) {}
     try
     {
       end = Math.abs(document.selection.createRange().moveEnd("character", -10000000)); // end
       if(end > 0)
       {
         try
         {
           var endReal = Math.abs(ctrl.createTextRange().moveEnd("character", -10000000));

           var r = document.body.createTextRange();
           r.moveToElementText(ctrl);
           var sTest = Math.abs(r.moveStart("character", -10000000));
           var eTest = Math.abs(r.moveEnd("character", -10000000));

           if ((ctrl.tagName.toLowerCase() != 'input') && (eTest - endReal == sTest))
            end -= sTest;
         }
         catch(err) {}
       }
     }
     catch (e) {}
     insertionS = start;
     insertionE = end
   } }  function setRange(ctrl, start, end) {
   if(ctrl.setSelectionRange) // Standard way (Mozilla, Opera, ...)
   {   ctrl.setSelectionRange(start, end);
   }
   else // MS IE
   {
     var range;
     try
     { range = ctrl.createTextRange();
     }
     catch(e)
     {try
       {
         range = document.body.createTextRange();
         range.moveToElementText(ctrl);
       }
       catch(e)
       {
         range = null;
       }
     } if(!range) return;
    range.collapse(true);
     range.moveStart("character", start);
     range.moveEnd("character", end - start);
     range.select();
   }
   insertionS = start;
   insertionE = end;
 }function deleteSelection(ctrl) {
   if(insertionS == insertionE) return;  var tmp = (document.selection && !window.opera) ? ctrl.value.replace(/\r/g,"") : ctrl.value;
   ctrl.value = tmp.substring(0, insertionS) + tmp.substring(insertionE, tmp.length);
   setRange(ctrl, insertionS, insertionS);}
 function deleteAtCaret(ctrl)     {
   // if(insertionE < insertionS) insertionE = insertionS;
   if(insertionS != insertionE)
   {
     deleteSelection(ctrl);
     return;
   }
   if(insertionS == insertionE)
     insertionS = insertionS - 1;
   var tmp = (document.selection && !window.opera) ? ctrl.value.replace(/\r/g,"") : ctrl.value;
   ctrl.value = tmp.substring(0, insertionS) + tmp.substring(insertionE, tmp.length);
   setRange(ctrl, insertionS, insertionS);
 } // This function inserts text at the caret position:
 //
 function insertAtCaret(ctrl, val)
 {
   if(insertionS != insertionE) deleteSelection(ctrl);

   if(isgecko && document.createEvent && !window.opera)
   {
     var e = document.createEvent("KeyboardEvent");

     if(e.initKeyEvent && ctrl.dispatchEvent)
     {
       e.initKeyEvent("keypress",        // in DOMString typeArg,
                      false,             // in boolean canBubbleArg,
                      true,              // in boolean cancelableArg,
                      null,              // in nsIDOMAbstractView viewArg, specifies UIEvent.view. This value may be null;
                      false,             // in boolean ctrlKeyArg,
                      false,             // in boolean altKeyArg,
                      false,             // in boolean shiftKeyArg,
                      false,             // in boolean metaKeyArg,
                      null,              // key code;
                      val.charCodeAt(0));// char code.

       ctrl.dispatchEvent(e);
     }
   }
   else
   {
     var tmp = (document.selection && !window.opera) ? ctrl.value.replace(/\r/g,"") : ctrl.value;
     ctrl.value = tmp.substring(0, insertionS) + val + tmp.substring(insertionS, tmp.length);
   } setRange(ctrl, insertionS + val.length, insertionS + val.length);} //--><</SCRIPT>><</HEAD>><BODY> <P style="font-family:Tahoma;font-size:14px">Virtual keyboard/numpad installation.</P><TABLE border="0" width="60%"> <TR>
 <TD width="100px"><TEXTAREA id="textfield" rows="2" cols="50" onkeyup="getCaretPositions(this);" onclick="getCaretPositions(this);"></TEXTAREA></TD></TR></TABLE><P><A href="javascript:numpad_change()" onclick="javascript:blur()" id="switch" style="font-family:Tahoma;font-size:14px;text-decoration:none;border-bottom: 1px dashed #0000F0;color:#0000F0">Show numpad</A></P><DIV id="numpad"></DIV></BODY></HTML>
```

You can also segregate the JS and HTML code by putting the JS in a separate file as numpad.js.

Answer (score 2):

You can check this russian project:

http://debugger.ru/en/projects/virtualkeyboard

Even if many pages are in russian language.
Maybe you can create a new layout with just the keys you need.

Hope this can help!